# require fails when running unit test in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

So when I try to run the below file, I get this error. When I run it using ruby -I Zombifier_test.rb, it gets stuck forever and hangs. How do I make this work?

```
 ruby Zombifier_test.rb

/home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- Zombifier (LoadError)
    from /home/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from Zombifier_test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Contents of Zombifier_test.rb file are below:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'Zombifier'

class ZombifierTest< Test::Unit::TestCase

  # Called before every test method runs. Can be used
  # to set up fixture information.
  def test_zombify_upcase
     z=Zombifier.new("Hello World")

    assert_equal "HELLO WORLD BRAINS",z.zombify,"They are not equal"

    end



end
```

Contents of Zombifier.rb are below:

```
class Zombifier

  def initialize(str)
    @str = str
  end

  def zombify
    "#{@str} BRAINS"
  end

end
```

Contents of the tests directory are as below:

```
4096 Mar  9 14:28 ..
 106 Mar  9 14:36 zombifier.rb
4096 Mar  9 14:38 .idea
4096 Mar  9 14:53 coverage
 323 Mar  9 15:00 Zombifier_test.rb_bk
 379 Mar  9 15:19 Zombifier_test.rb
4096 Mar  9 15:19 .
```

Comment: You should use `require_relative`, not `require`.

Comment: I tried this. It does not work. Zombifier_test.rb:2:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/tests/Zombifier (LoadError)
 from Zombifier_test.rb:2:in `<main>'require '/home/tests/Zombifier'

Comment: Try `ruby -I test path/zombifier_test.rb`

Comment: Nope. This also not working. Tried it just now. Same error as mentioned before

Comment: Try requiring the file not the class `require 'zombifier.rb'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like that on top of test file (before requires):

```
$: << "../src" # path to zombifier.rb relative to zombifier_test.rb
```

Comment: I tried this require '/home/tests/Zombifier' in the test file . does not work.

Comment: I tried that. Does not work .require 'test/unit'
$: << "/home/tests/"
require 'Zombifier'

Comment: 4096 Mar  9 14:28 ..
 106 Mar  9 14:36 zombifier.rb
4096 Mar  9 14:38 .idea
4096 Mar  9 14:53 coverage
 323 Mar  9 15:00 Zombifier_test.rb_bk
 379 Mar  9 15:19 Zombifier_test.rb
4096 Mar  9 15:19 .

Comment: zombifier.rb is not the same as Zombifier.rb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72605/discussion-between-iced-and-zack).